# I have a date variable and I've never seen the numbers like this.. can someone explain

Tags: php

```
$last = $today - (60*60*24*90); //90 days ago
```

Obviously i see the commented out line that says this is equivalent to 90 days but can someone explain exactly what each number is doing.

The asterisk is multiplying each number but it's confusing. Is that seconds or microseconds?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$today is a timestamp, such as `1424800194`

> The timestamp is the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Your example minuses 60 (seconds) * 60 (minutes) * 24 (hours) * 90 (days)

More info about timestamps: http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Comment: So how would i set it to like 1 day, just change the 90 on the end to 1?

Comment: 60 * 60 * 24 would be 1 day

Comment: Thank you sir, I'll mark you as the correct answer.